# Sending My App URL Scheme Using WhatsApp URL Scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, nsurl, whatsapp

Maybe I'm missing something simple here, but I cannot for the life of me get my `URL` to show up on the `WhatsApp` app using their `URL` scheme. I have:

```
        NSString *stringToSend = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=myAppDomain://%@moreChars",specialString] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringToSend];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
```

It successfully launches the `WhatsApp` app, however after I pick a contact, the message box is not pre-filled, it remains empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you send other text? (i.e. not your URL)

Comment: Yes it does. It works for both when I hard code the word or when I use stringWithFormat

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Michel No I have not unfortunately. But I have not tried since March.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got solution to share own application itunes URL to whatsapp.

```
NSString *string = [@"" stringByAppendingFormat:@"Share this on whatsapp \n\n https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-search/id284815942?mt=8"];

 string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];

  NSLog(@">>>Just pass this to Whatspp using their URL scheme %@",string);
```

I tested this well. :)
Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

This is complete code to send text and URL both in WhatsApp

```
    NSString * msg = @"Application%20Name%20https://itunes.apple.com/YOUR-URL";

    msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%3A"];
    msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F"];
    msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F"];
    msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%2C"];
    msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];
    msg = [msg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];

    NSString * urlWhats = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",msg];
    NSURL * whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlWhats];
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Your device has no WhatsApp installed." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is you attached string UTFEncoded? I mean this is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding with WhatsApp. Try the following code which worked for me:

```
NSString *theTempMessage,*theFinalMessage;
.......
    /// theTempMessage should contain your stringToSend (in its current state);
    theTempMessage = [theTempMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"%3A"];
    theTempMessage = [theTempMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"%2F"];
    theTempMessage = [theTempMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"?" withString:@"%3F"];
    theTempMessage = [theTempMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"%2C"];
    theTempMessage = [theTempMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"];
    theFinalMessage = [theTempMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];
    stringToSend=theFinalMessage;
```

At this point your stringToSend should contain something working.
Please try it and let me know.

I hope this helps.